# Oracle DB: Data type conversion problem when using a union

Tags: oracle, union, data-conversion, clob

So, I have two tables in an Oracle database. The relevant column (let's call it `field_x`) is of type `CLOB` in `table_a` and `VARCHAR2(510)` in `table_b`.

If I run any of these queries, everything works fine:

```
SELECT cast(field_x AS VARCHAR2(510)) AS x FROM table_a WHERE some-condition;
SELECT field_x AS x FROM table_b WHERE some-condition;
```

But if I combine the output of those same query with a union, a problem arises:

```
SELECT cast(field_x AS VARCHAR2(510)) AS x FROM table_a WHERE some-condition
UNION
SELECT field_x AS x FROM table_b WHERE some-condition;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P00M, instance such-and-such
ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 4718, maximum: 4000)
```

What could be the reason? Each query works fine on its own, so it's not like there are any clob values longer than 510 characters.

Comment: you can't union different types like that. Try casting the the 510 field to a clob also

Comment: That's why the cast. Without the cast, the query indeed doesn't compile (DataGrid complains about different types). But with the cast, it runs, though with the above error. Casting to a CLOB fails with: "inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB"

Comment: You say "each query works fine on its own, so it's not like there are any CLOB values longer than 510 characters". That is simply false. The second query works on its own. In that query you select from a different table (compared to the first query). This other table, your `table_b`, may very well contain `varchar2` of length greater than 510 in column `field_x` - the query would still work perfectly fine. Why wouldn't it? What does the second query have to do with "510 characters"?

Comment: Could it be that the cast is just silently ignored in the successful case if the length is too high?

Comment: Maybe I should do dbms_lob.substr

Answer (score 0):

It works with `DBMS_LOB.substr` explicitly called:

```
SELECT cast(DBMS_LOB.substr(field_x, 510, 1) AS VARCHAR2(510)) AS x FROM table_a WHERE some-condition
UNION
SELECT field_x AS x FROM table_b WHERE some-condition;
```